# ExtJS pass variable from controller to view

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a base controller that has a user object that is bind with the user data after login success. At this point the view that I need to pass the user object is already instantiated. Here is my base controller:

```
Ext.define('App.abstract.app.Controller', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

        user: {} // user object that can be accessed by any controller

    });
```

Now, here is my **Main.js** controller that extends from my base controller and that implements the login function:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'App.abstract.app.Controller',

    refs: [{
        ref: 'main',
        selector: 'app-main'
    },
    {
        ref: 'header',
        selector: 'appheader'
    }],

    init: function (application) {
        this.control({
            "loginform": {
                loguser: this.onLoginUser
            },
            'app-main #logoutBtn': {
                //click: this.onLogoutUser
            }
        });
    },
    onLoginUser: function (form, values) {
        var me = this;
        values.password = App.util.MD5.encode(values.password);
        App.util.Ajax.request({
            url: '/api/Security/ValidateUser',
            jsonData: values,
            success: function (response, opts) {
                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (obj.success) {

                    // sets the base controller user object so it can be available in all app
                    Ext.apply(me.user, obj.data);

                    me.getMain().layout.setActiveItem(1);

                    // HERE I WANT TO PASS MY me.user TO MY MAIN.js VIEW 

                }
            }
        });
    },

    }
});
```

Here is my **Main.js** view where I need to get the user object to I can set the User name in my footer (south panel).

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Card',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border',
        'Ext.layout.container.Accordion',
        'Ext.form.Label',
        'App.view.login.LoginForm',
        'App.view.Dashboard',
        'App.view.MainPanel',
        'App.view.Header',
        'App.view.menu.Accordion'
    ],


    xtype: 'app-main',
    layout: {
        type: 'card'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        defaults: { flex: 1 },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component'
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
            },
            defaults: { flex: 1 },
            items: [{ xtype: 'component' }, { xtype: 'loginform' }, { xtype: 'component' }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'component'
        }]
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: {
            type: 'border'
        },
        items: [
       {
           xtype: 'mainmenu',
           width: 250,
           region: 'west'
       },
       {
           xtype: 'appheader',
           region: 'north'
       },
       {
           xtype: 'mainpanel',
           region: 'center'
       },
       {
           xtype: 'container',
           region: 'south',
           items:
               [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        margin: '0',
                        style: 'background-color:#3892D3;',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'displayfield',
                                id: 'username',
                                fieldLabel: 'User Name',
                                width: 100,
                                labelWidth: 70,
                                style: 'color:#FFFFFF;',
                                value: '<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:12px">HERE I NEED THE USER NAME</span>'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
               ]
       }
        ]
    }
    ]
});
```

Any clue?

Comment: Give your display field an itemId, and then just update it: me.getMain().down( '#someDisplayField' ).update( me.user )

Comment: Is the main view already rendered at this point or not?